# iOS GMaps removing old GMSMarker from map

Tags: ios, google-maps

I want to add new GMSMarker in the map and remove the old one. Previously I was using `[map clear];` method and adding new marker. It was working fine. But I dont want that. I want to add new marker and remove the old marker without clearing the map each time.

My code:

```
if(markerMYLocation == nil)
{
    markerMYLocation = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
}
markerMYLocation.map = nil;
markerMYLocation.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude_Point, longitude_Point);
markerMYLocation.title = @"You";
markerMYLocation.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
markerMYLocation.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"white.png"];
markerMYLocation.map = mapViewGoog;
```

Question:
1) What is the correct way of removing and adding the marker?

2)I am initializing marker only in my viewDidLoad. Is that the correct way of doing this or should I initialize each time I add it?

Answer (score 0):

Marker add on Map View

```
    GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:[marker.getcoordinateObject MKCoordinateValue]];
    marker.icon =[UIImage imageNamed:@“”];

    marker.title = @“Driver Pin”            
    marker.map = mapView_;
    [allMarkeronMap addObject:googleMapsDriverPin]; // Add maker on Array
    [_mapView addSubview:mapView_];
```

//Make MutableArray on viewDidLoad

```
   NSMutableArray * allMarkeronMap =[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

particualr marker or old marker remove on mapView

```
 for (GMSMarker *pin in allMarkeronMap) {
    if (pin.userData == @"Driver Pin"){ 
        pin.map = nil; 
    }
}
```